# Can't see my Azure VMs listed in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

Whenever I try to get a list of VMs I have running in Azure, they aren't showing up when I use PowerShell to list them. I know they are they exist because I see them in the portal but when I connect using Powershell with the same account I can't find them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you have multiple accounts and the default account is expired or no longer valid.  To solve the problem, you simple tell PowerShell to forget all your accounts and then just reconnect to your account again.  It looks something like this...

## AzureAccount = Cached Credentials

Get-AzureAccount

## Clear Cached Credentials

Get-AzureAccount | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureAccount $_.ID -Force }

#

## Authenticate to Azure w/ UserName and Password:

Add-AzureAccount